# $UnionWith pipeline filter

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use the $UnionWith on my aggregation pipeline to do something like this:

ParentObject

```
db.getCollection("col").aggregate(
[
   //Filtering the master
   {$match:{'_id':ObjectId('62722c260ee18a304784d8cf')}},
   //then we want to bring all data which holds the same type
   {$unionWith: { coll: "col", pipeline: [{$match:{'Type':"$Type"}}]}}
])
```

Basically I want to return a list with the '62722c260ee18a304784d8cf' object and all other objects that holds the 'Type' property...

As far as I could see, it seems this would not be possible, or am I missing something?

Basically the "$Type" does not get resolved...

Thanks in advance!

PCBL

Comment: better provide example document from the collection and expected output , since it is not very clear what exactly you want to achieve with unionWith on same collection  , maybe $lookup is your option ...

Comment: HI @R2D2,

As simple as that:

```
_id                                                   Name       Type
62722c260ee18a304784d8cf     A               D
62722c260ee18a304784d8cj      B               D
62722c260ee18a304784d8ck     C               D
62722c260ee18a304784d8ck     D               E
```

If I run my query from above, I expect to get A,B,C... D would not come because it does not have same type as A(62722c260ee18a304784d8cf)

Comment: check this answer here can give you ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674629/lookup-with-same-collection